# how to check number in range with n level

Tags: javascript, math, web

Today i have a hard work, and hard issue:

- lets say i have js function which each time we call it, it return a number :
- let's say i have list number from 1 to 100 in array, and make it into columns and rows:

  ```
  1 2 3 4  5  6

  7 8 9 10 11 12

  13 14 15 16 17

  18 19 20 21 ...
  ```
- each time call function, it return random number in 1 > 100, but i need to check:
  `if number is 1, 2, 3 or 7, 8, 9` ( because array number will sort to 6 columns each row, so i need to detect number return from function is one of 3 digis left, or 3 digis right ).

and because `number range not fixed`, i dont know what math or solution to detect this case.
anyone know it?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you've written already, even if it's not working. We're here to help you, not do your work for you.

Comment: Not ready :(. because i'm stuck about how to calculate and detect number return from function will stay on col: 1 2 3 or 4 5 6. I mean if number is 1 or 2 or 3 or 7 or 8 or 9... other code really not glue with this issue

Comment: @Matt : thank you for fix my question. I'm not usually ask in stack overflow only when i can not solve my issue. And i don't want ask somebody work for me too. I am not stuck in code, i stuck on solution how to calculate and i ask about solution, not ask how to write in code. Please understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a column number (or, more precisely, "left 3 or right 3") subtract 1 and do a `%` modulus operator: `(value-1) % 6`. The result will be 0..2 (or "left column") or 3..5 (so "right column").

Comment: Thank you. i tried and it work! this is the solution i need. Thankyou again.